# DISM Srv2012r2 - Capture multiple file in parallel

Tags: dism

I wrote a powershell script to capture a bunch of virtual machines, one by one. As this process takes some time, I want to capture them in parallel.

Setting up the parameters is not the point. What makes me stumble is the DISM error 
"Failed to write the logfile: The process cannot access dism.log because it is being used by another process"

Any idead how to fix this or force DISM to ignore errors?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, as it was pinned down in the error message: DISM has the parameter "/LogPath". Just specify a different logpath in every call. With that you could call dism in parallel as much as you want.